# JToggleButton inside JToolbar on macOS - no indication of being pressed

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtoolbar, jtogglebutton

I can't seem to get simple toggle buttons working inside a JToolbar.

This example program adds three toggle buttons in a button group to a JToolbar. On macOS, currenty toggled button is only visible if the app looses focus.

[image: focused]

[image: no focus]

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo extends JFrame {

    public Foo() {
        setTitle("Foo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.setFloatable(false);
        add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JToggleButton well = new JToggleButton("Well Done"); 
        JToggleButton medium = new JToggleButton("Medium");
        JToggleButton rare = new JToggleButton("Rare");

        toolbar.add(well);
        toolbar.add(medium);        
        toolbar.add(rare);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(well);
        group.add(medium);
        group.add(rare);

        setSize(400, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {   
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Foo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a known issue with such usage of toggle buttons on macOS? Any workarounds?

This is with macOS version 10.14.5, Oracle/OpenJDK JRE/JDK 1.8 and 11.

Comment: Yes, there is an issue.

Comment: [This](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8224712?jql=labels%20%3D%20macos), probably. Would still appreciate a workaround.

Comment: use another laf

Comment: In my specific case, since the layout of the buttons allowed it, the workaround was to move the toggle buttons outside of the toolbar. macOS users will just have to deal with slightly different visualization of those buttons.